# Get PsiElement from Python class name in IntelliJ Platform SDK

Tags: pycharm, intellij-plugin

I'm creating a PyCharm/IntelliJ plugin using the IntelliJ Platform SDK, and I'm creating a `CompletionContributor` implementation. In PyCharm, by turning on "Auto-display documentation," you can show the pydoc for the class that's being completed, like this:
[image: completion with documentation]

As I understand, to do this in custom completions, I need to call the `LookupElement.withPsiElement` method (though the documentation is lacking, so I could be wrong). Thus, I'd like to get the `PsiElement` of a specific class (or method) by name as painlessly as possible.

For example, if I wanted to replicate the completion above, I'd like to get the `PsiElement` for the Python class `apache_beam.transforms.combiners.Count`. This class is in another package (apache-beam) but for the purposes of this question it is safe to assume that the user has already installed the necessary package.

It seems like it should be possible to do what I'm trying to do, given that PyCharm already does something very similar. Am I approaching this the right way? Is there a convenient way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

See `com.jetbrains.python.codeInsight.completion.PyClassNameCompletionContributor` class and `com.jetbrains.python.psi.PyPsiFacade#createClassByQName` method.